# Handling race condition to load a Scroll View within fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am currently using a Scroll View to show some details about restaurants. The information being shown is loaded from a volley request as shown below.

```
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    //hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            String winName = obj.getString("name");

                            Log.d(winName, getShownName());

                            if(getShownName().toLowerCase().equals(winName.toLowerCase())) {
                                Log.d("creating element ", getShownName());
                                //do stuff
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //hidePDialog();

        }
});

    // Adding request to request queue
    volleySingleton.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
```

This is done within onCreate of the fragment and in onCreateView I want to use this information to set textViews and other Views within the ScrollView however onCreateView is called before volley is done thus none of the information I need is ready.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't set the view text in onCreateView(). Create a reference to the views there and then call a method that sets their values from your volley responses.

Comment: Ah, and when I do textView.setText the scrollView will then update? I will probably set some sort of loading icon within the onCreateView() and remove it in the method called from within onResponse() of volley. Thanks!

Comment: That is correct :) You can look into ProgressBar as it will likely do what you need. Best of luck!